# How to switch to previous version of mozila using developer tools?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, opera, ie-developer-tools

I am working on a project, which is under testing now. Need is to make Website compatible with all Modern as well as at-least make them compatible with 2 older versions of every Major browsers.

For this I used IE <kbd>F12</kbd> tools in IE, to Switch to IE 9,8,7 view.

Now is there any Tool for Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera, which let me switch to its previous version for testing?

Comment: Can't speak for Opera and Safari, but for Firefox and Chrome, no there is not.  Also, make sure you be careful about IE 8 and 7 mode in IE 9 as they are not 100% matches for actual IE 8 and 7.

Comment: yes IE tooks most of time, just checked Mozilla's FireBug, it does't support this feature. It seems I have install there Previous versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't - you need to install different versions of the browsers. This is absolutely unproblematic with Firefox, just specify a different installation path for the old version (note that only one Firefox instance can run at a time unless you create different profiles and use `-no-remote` command line flag). I think that it is similar with Safari and Opera. Chrome is complicated however, you simply cannot install a version older than the current release - with some luck you can find it on [PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) (it will be slightly broken). You can have Chrome versions from different channels (e.g. Release and Beta) but you have to install them under different user accounts.